# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nvidia.dali.backend_impl' when running nvidia/deeplearningexamples reponstory

Tags: python, nvidia

run rn50 scripts in NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples, as

```
./rn50_partial.sh
```

get error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/export/nfs/sunxue/DeepLearningExamples/PyTorch/Classification/ConvNets/mnasnet/training/FP32/../../../launch.py", line 7, in <module>

    from main import main, add_parser_arguments, available_models

  File "/export/nfs/sunxue/DeepLearningExamples/PyTorch/Classification/ConvNets/main.py", line 49, in <module>

    from image_classification.dataloaders import *

  File "/export/nfs/sunxue/DeepLearningExamples/PyTorch/Classification/ConvNets/image_classification/dataloaders.py", line 79, in <module>

    class HybridTrainPipe(Pipeline):

NameError: name 'Pipeline' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I've solved this, cause NVIDIA does not classify the specific installation, actually, it does not have to install from scratch, if you use pip install, just check which version NVIDIA docker use and download this specific version, pip install, and everything will be ok.